# Is it possible to write this VBA code any better?

Tags: ms-access, vba

Am I reinventing the wheel here?  Is there a better way to do this?  This VBA function looks for the first instance of a string in the comment field of a form in Access containing 20 characters or less, no spaces, surrounded by (~) tildes, then returns it.

```
Public Function ParseComment(strComment As String) As String

'  This function parses the comment field of the job entry dialog for (~) tilde 
'  surrounded text, then returns that text.

Dim intCounter As Integer
Dim intFirstChar As Integer
Dim intLastChar As Integer
Dim strResult As String

intFirstChar = 0
intLastChar = 0
intCounter = 0

Do While (intLastChar = 0) And (intCounter < Len(strComment))
    intCounter = intCounter + 1

    strCharacter = Mid(strComment, intCounter, 1)

    If (strCharacter = "~") Then
        If intFirstChar Then
            intLastChar = intCounter
        Else
            intFirstChar = intCounter + 1
        End If
    End If

Loop

strResult = Mid(strComment, intFirstChar, intLastChar - intFirstChar)

If (intLastChar - intFirstChar <= 20) And (intFirstChar <> 0 Or intLastChar <> 0) And Not InStr(strResult, " ") Then
    ParseComment = strResult
End If

End Function
```

Thanks much.

Comment: It is always possible to write code better, but if this works for you why bother ?

Comment: Just a side note you can do `Dim intFirstChar as Integer=0` it can clean up the code a bit with all your initilizations, intialize them when you declare them.

Comment: @JonH "Dim intFirstChar As Integer = 0" will cause a compile error in VBA. VBA already initializes local integer variables to zero, so even if it was possible it would be pointless. It works in VB.NET however.

Comment: Ahh ok didn't know that and just noticed it was vba, thought he was just doing vb.net.  Thanks

Comment: This question is dangerously close to a vote close for "not constructive" or "not a real question", since "Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page." (FAQ) I think you should state a clear concern and narrow your question. Just saying.

Comment: For the record, this kind of quesion should be better on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (i.e. "It works but maybe could be improved)

Comment: @Jmax:  Thank you for the suggestion.  Stack Exchange really needs an organized list of forums.  I don't have the time I go through that randomized list every time I need to ask a question.

Comment: @Albion: I know there are several somehow similar Q&A stackexchange websites. I would not advise you to find the best one each time you have a question but next time, for this *kind* of question, you'll know that it exists :)

Answer (score 3):

I would use `InStr` to find the first and second occurences of the ~ character, something like this, rather than looping manually:

```
Public Function ParseComment(strComment As String) As String

'  This function parses the comment field of the job entry dialog for (~) tilde
'  surrounded text, then returns that text.

Dim firstTilde As Integer
Dim secondTilde As Integer
Dim strResult As String

firstTilde = 0
secondTilde = 0
strResult = ""

firstTilde = InStr(strComment, "~")

If firstTilde > 0 Then

    secondTilde = InStr(firstTilde + 1, strComment, "~")

    If (secondTilde > 0) And (secondTilde < 20) Then

        strResult = Mid(strComment, firstTilde, secondTilde)

        If InStr(strResult, " ") = 0 Then

            ParseComment = strResult
        End If
    End If
End If

End Function
```

[Disclaimer, I haven't tested this!]

Answer (score 0):

Using the built-in functions might be a little quicker, but don't imagine it will make a critical difference...

Something like:

```
Public Function getTildeDelimStringPart(inputstring As String) As String

Dim commentStart As Long, commentEnd As Long

commentStart = InStr(1, inputstring, "~")

If commentStart = 0 Then ' no tilde
    getTildeDelimStringPart = vbNullString
    Exit Function
End If

commentEnd = InStr(1 + commentStart, inputstring, "~")
If commentEnd = 0 Then
    getTildeDelimStringPart = vbNullString
    Exit Function
End If

getTildeDelimStringPart = Mid(inputstring, commentStart, commentEnd - commentStart + 1)

End Function
```

Comment: It is a good habit to leverage built-in functions whenever possible. There may be some cases in some languages where it is only marginally faster, but most of the time you win. In the `instr` case, it is also partly a change in algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
Public Function ParseComment(strComment As String) As String

Dim regex As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp
Dim regexmatch As Object ' VBScript_RegExp_55.MatchCollection
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript_RegExp_55.RegExp")

With regex
  .MultiLine = False
  .Global = False
  .IgnoreCase = True
  .Pattern = "(~[^ ~]{1,20}~)"
End With

Set regexmatch = regex.Execute(strComment)

If regexmatch.Count > 0 Then
  ParseComment = regexmatch(0)
End If

End Function
```

You can add additional parsing at the end if you want to remove the tilde characters.

I tested it on the following string:

**ABC~123aA%dwdD~CBA**

the function returns **~123aA%dwdD~**

Forgot to mention that this code requires VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5 which is located in %windir%\system32\vbscript.dll\3, although the code is late bound so you should just be able to drop it into your project.

Comment: Your regex does not follow the pattern of not allowing for spaces (or other ~). Should be "(~[^ ~]{1,20}~)" That would allow for 1 to 20 characters that are not spaces or ~.

Comment: I didn't know VBA could do RegEx. Thanks JP, I'm going to try this.

Comment: I generally do not use regular expressions for simple parsing like in the question, because the overhead of regular expressions doesn't have enough complexity to work with, therefore it is generally slower.

Comment: @Issun -- OP's code does not account for tildes mid-string. I probably should not have included "%" in my example because OP states his strings are all text in between the tildes. Also, number of characters is irrelevant. OP wants all characters between tildes.

Comment: OP stated "20 characters or less" and "no spaces". If you have ~xxx~xx~ you can say that there are 6 characters between 2 tildes, but more correct is to say that there are 2 sets of characters surounded by tildes, one with 3 characters, and one with 2. :)

Answer (score 0):

I see everyone has given you some more ways to do this (**instr** is a great way, see Vicky's answer!), so I'll just list up some tips on optimizing your code:

- Use Long instead of Integer. VBA will convert them to Long every time.
- Default value for Int and Long is 0 in VBA, so no need to declare them so.
- Use Mid$ instead of Mid
- Using Instr() would be a very effecient way to find location of ~

Fun Tip: If you do want to evaluate each character, fastest way is numeric comparision:

```
if Asc(Mid$(strComment, intCounter, 1)) = 126 Then
```